# Ubuntu Run terminal as a different user

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do I run the terminal in Ubuntu as a different user than the one I am currently logged in as?

This is what I want to do:

Log in to user A.
Open the terminal as user B.
Open new tabs and terminal windows as user B simply by keying ctrl-shift-t and ctrl-shift-n.

Right now, whenever I want to open a new tab or terminal windows as user B, I have to su - username, type in the password, and then cd to the directory I want - and that's just unacceptable for an aspiring superuser.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own launcher with command:

```
 gksu -u USER_NAME_B /usr/bin/x-terminal-emulator
```

It prompts password like when opening synaptic, write password and whole application is opened as USER_NAME_B user, so new tabs should be opened as that user.

Comment: This didn't work for me. It just returned me to the terminal I was already using under the current login.